# Performance problems using new fork join framework of jdk 7

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, fork-join

I'm using the new forkjoin framework of jdk 7.
I got a task, which has to be performed multiple times with different parameters.

This task extends `RecursiveTask`. there are more than 100 tasks to perform, which can performed concurrently. the tasks are independent, so there should be no need for any synchronisation. 
Therefore I created at first the needed tasks and passed them to forkjoin thread pool.
but the application becomes slower, than running it without any parallelism.

My first thought was, that i create to much threads..  Thats why i tried to recycle the threads to reduce object creation overhead, but this has no effect on the performance. for recycling im using the reinitialize() method. Also with recycling the performance is slower than running it without any parallelism.

The operations performed in the tasks are not trivial, the duration of running threads are from 5 to 150 ms.   The application runs on a dualcore machine and im using ubuntu and oracle jdk 7.

Comment: Have  you built a simple program, that simply forks a task and waits for it to complete, with the thread doing zero work, to get a sense of the context switching times? Do you know what those times are?

Comment: ... you'll note with 2 processors your speedup is at most 2x.  You sure you need 100 independent tasks?

Comment: i will try out your first comment :) As said, im not using anymore 100 independent threads. I created a fixed amount of threads, which are objects that extends RecursiveTask<T> as shown in many examples, e.g. 2. Afterwards i setup the parameters of those objects and passing them to pool, to run concurrently. Afterwards i resetup the parameters, as long as elements are available, for which the tasks has to be performed.

Comment: Is a duration of 5 to 150 ms not enough, to use threads ?

Comment: What matters with parallelism is the amount of work you can, compared to the overhead to manage it.   If forking costs 50 milliseconds , and you have 50 milliseconds of work to do, you have only 50% efficiency.  With two CPUs you could at best hope to break even compared to one CPU.   So, knowing your overhead matters.  I don't know that Java forks take this long (no experience at all), and that seems like an uneasonably high number to me.  Hence the suggestion to measure it.

Comment: i tried the example you had suggested. i just implemented an empty compute() method in the recursive task, which returns null. i'm using pool.invoke(task) to maintain the the procedure blocks until task is finished. the result was less 0ms, so i think the switching time is in range of nanoseconds.

Comment: @IraBaxter That sounds like Amdahl's Law to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law :)

Comment: Can anybody give me a hint, how long a thread should run at least? Is it possible, that the amount of work is not enough in my case to justify the usage of threads ? The most threads have a average duration ~50ms. But some of the threads are quite longer (exceeds 150ms)

Comment: It's really hard to help when you haven't described what the threads are doing (aside from "non trivial"). e.g., if they do any file I/O, many threads hitting the disk will probably end up slowing things down because of seek times. You can also use jvisualvm as a poor-man's CPU profiler.

Comment: @lunatikz:  You ought to run your test for a million forks, and divide elapsed time by a million.  With a clock rate of 10 ms/tick, it might just be that one fork takes less than one tick (it should), but thus gets measured as zero.   (barely) "Nanoseconds" is an ideal context switching time but I have some difficulty believing Java can achieve that.

Comment: @vanza: Im trying to implement the espresso algorithm (multiple valued boolean minimization). I have to deal with cubes, which are binary encodings of terms of a logical formula. I use int variables to maintain this. The operation performed on these cubes are mostly bitwise logical operations. So there is no I/O stuff at all. But the amount of cubes is expected to be large, thats why i wanted to use threads to determine if a decomposed function with a cube is a tautology, for example. E.g. those Examination of being a Taut, has to be performed upto 100 times for different cubes

Comment: Thats what i want to do concurrently, someone would say is for this case not the best solution. the f&j fw was used before to fork threads in recursive tasks. but this was not useful, because i had created in this case more than ~5000 threads (recursive tasks), for a runtime duration of 10 seconds overall.

Comment: Souds like your code is CPU-bound only, so most of the overhead will be along the lines of that Ira has been talking about. Since you have two cores, have you tried running two tasks/threads only, to minimize context switching overhead?

Comment: yes i tried this, a slightly performance gain was achieved, but there is no speed up in common sense. multiple test run of the program measures different computation time (from 1.3 to 3.8 seconds). With the limitation on 2 threads, i achieve 1.0 - 2.5 seconds. the non parallized version runs the same in maxium 1 second.

Comment: Also i dont understand, why the computation time differs that much with the same settings and function to minimize. The best result for the paralell version was 0.8 sec. But this occured only in 3/10 testruns.

Comment: So are you measuring speedup on end-to-end program execution time, or are you measuring speedup over what you believe to be the parallel part?  Amdahl's law was raised earlier, reasonably, and it applies here, too: if your program takes 5 seconds to set up, and goes 2x parallel for 1 second, your end-to-end time is 6 seconds vs. 7 for a 16% speedup.   For paralellism to help, it has to be the predomination execution mode pretty much all the time.  [Did you figure our what the actual task time was?]

Comment: No, I'm measuring the speed up only on the parallel part, comparing that with counterpart in non paralellism version. Im sorry im not that much experienced in parallelism. What does predomination execution mode means ? tried googling it, but i didnt found useful websites. All parallel tasks complete within the range of 1.0-2,5 seconds. A single task completes within 5 to 150 ms. But all values differs pretty much for different test runs, with the same function and settings.

Comment: How about showing us a little code? The F/J framework is severely restricted in the amount of work necessary to make it work. [article] (http://coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html#special)

Answer (score 0):

Edward Harned of CoopSoft has found numerous problems with the Fork/Join design implemented in Java.

In particular, "work-stealing" suffers high contention & is inefficient at spreading work around multiple processors. Recursive decomposition is also not particularly efficient.

If your tasks are *not* recursive -- you say there are 100, and they can be performed concurrently -- then a simpler approach using ThreadPoolExecutor may likely be more efficient.

See:

- http://literatejava.com/threading/fork-join-parallelization-feature-or-problem/
- http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html

Comment: Here is another good article, which gives a more balanced view IMO: http://moi.vonos.net/java/forkjoin/ . Some rules of thumb with FJPs seem to be: 1. Avoid using the common pool since the JVM/libraries might be using that. 2. Avoid blocking in a thread, since FJP is fixed size (CPU-bound tasks only) 3. Set thresholds for switching to serial from recursive, otherwise you might blow up the stack since every join() runs the new task in the same thread. So I think FJP is best for CPU-bound divide-and-merge with shallow depth but large branching (i.e. many tasks)